# JQUERY: How to select dropdown (select) element of selected <option>

Tags: jquery, selector, each

I have a dropdown list that could look like this

```
<select>
   <option value='1' isgood='1' />
   <option value='1' isbad='1' />
</select>
```

Lets assume option 1 is selected on the page.

I select all options on a page with the custom attribute "isgood". This way i can get the value of the option. But i need to access the "select" object.

```
$('select id='myid' name='myname' option[isgood]:selected').each(function (d, elem) {
}
```

How do i do this ?

I have tried using the .parent and .parents but they return not the select element but som HTML element(s).

So in short:

I need to select all options on the entire page thats:
1. selected in a dropdown list
2. has the custom attribute "isgood"
3. loop though the options, and get the value
4. get the id/name of the "select" object

hope u can help

/Bo

Comment: you mean in your page there are several `<select>`?

Comment: I don't see what you need the id or the name for! More information please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a falsy selector. Your code:

```
$('select id='myid' name='myname' option[isgood]:selected')
```

would look for selects that have children of type id that have children of type and so on...

why dont you select the options and their parents like so:

```
$('option[isgood]').filter(':selected').each(function() {
    var option = $(this),
        select = option.parent(),
        id = select.attr('id');

    console.log(id);
});
```